# Getting error, ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed. windows

Tags: ruby, windows, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-5, minimagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to manipulate photos in my rails app but when I upload the photo and post it I get this error,

"Picture Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed"

Also when I try do,

```
irb
require 'mini_magick'
filename = '/Users/me/tmp/testfile.jpg'
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(filename)
```

it gives error "gives error...MiniMagick::Invalid: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed"

ImageMagick is added to the system path, and installed successfully, I can open imagemagick through the cmd line and bring up the interface, wondering if anyone can offer some help.

correct versions are installed of ImageMagick for my operating system.

Also vcomp120.dll is installed as well.

EDIT: This is just on the development sever, not, in production.

Comment: There are lots of different API's for Imagemagick. You say you have installed Imagemagick but the error says you are trying to use Graphics magick. No idea what minimagick is - something to do with rails? Try installing Graphics Magick: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/ unless you should be installing via a different route with rails.

Comment: Yes. I will try and install graphicsmagic, I was going to do this, but forgot. Minimagic is the gem that rails uses for ImageMagick, and as for the route, I downloaded from the site and then tested it in the cmd line, and it worked fine, but maybe there is something else.

Comment: I posted the resolution to my question, now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer, my own question, on the ImageMagick website binaries download section, windows x64 I used and there it has a list of three commands

```
magick logo: "logo.gif"
magick identify "logo.gif"
magick display "logo.gif"
```

I was getting error `display: delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/1888.` with this. I then installed GraphicsMagick as per @Bonzo comment. Still had problems and read that alot of people were having trouble with converting images and installing the legacy utilities in the windows installer corrected this adding, convert.exe, mogrify, etc. I was then getting a error `...Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 62...` I then searched and found that other peoples were having trouble with this error, and to remove the program that is having the conflicting "libjpeg" file, for me this was GraphicsMagic, I uninstalled and displaying images is fine now.

Also check your delegates configuration `magick convert -list configure` and make sure jpeg or whatever format is in there you are wanting to use.